# what is Parse Error in css?

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to validate my css i get this error i tried to validate by direct input (copy and paste ) i still get this error. i tried to search on google why i get this error mostly was saying it has got something to do with space or {} these bracket but i checked everything i still get this error.

***104      Parse Error }***

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    width:100%;
}

li {
    float: left;

}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 24px;
    text-decoration: none;



}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}


table{

    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding:15px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    border:solid #ddd 3px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    white-space:pre-line;

}

td {
    border: solid #ddd 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding:10px;



}
th {
    border: solid #ddd 3px;

    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding:10px;

}
p {

    position: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.fix {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

h3,h2 {

font: bold italic 2em/1em "Times New Roman", "MS Serif", "New York", serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 30px;
color: #e7ce00;
text-align: center;

}

h2.login {
    text-align:center;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
.boxed {

    width: 300px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 70px;
    transform: translateX(120%) translateY(-5%);

}   

}
input.button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}


textarea {
    width: 99%;
    height: 150px;
}
input.text
{

 padding:15px;
 border:solid #ddd 3px;
 width: 97%;
 margin-top: 5px;


}
label {
        font-size: 18px;
                }
.search {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffe6e6;
}
```

Comment: Voting to close as a typo .... this isn't useful for future readers. have an extra closing `}` before `input.button`

Comment: typo to no use in future,,,

Comment: I agree. Moreover, it's so obvious you have to notice it on the first read. Also, this happens when you're messy and lazy and you don't format and indent your code properly. It's awful to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra closing curly brace:

```
.boxed {

    width: 300px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 70px;
    transform: translateX(120%) translateY(-5%);

}   

}
input.button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Hi - though a technically correct answer, for future reference please just point out the typo in the comments, and [flag to close](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a typo. Generally questions such as these aren't very valuable to future readers. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, will do that in the future.  I'm still learning the ropes.